# Proof attempt for uniqueness and existence of solutions for second order linear DE with complex valued solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about existence and uniqueness of solutions for a second order linear homogenous equation with constant complex coefficients. I have an attempt of a proof by reducing the equation to a system of real valued equations by separating the real and imaginary parts. Then the theorem should follow from the existence and uniqueness of solutions for systems of first order linear equations. Am I on the right track and are there any flaws in my proof? Below is the theorem and my proof.

$Theorem:$

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval and $x_0 \in U$. Let $p=a+bi$, $q=c+mi$, $z_0=t_0+is_0$ ja $z_1=t_1+is_1$ be some arbitrary complex numbers. The linear initial value problem
$  y''(x)+py'(x)+qy(x)=0, \;\; y(x_0)=z_0, \: y'(x_0)=z_1 $
has a solution $y:U \to \mathbb{C}, y(x)=u(x)+iv(x)$ on the entire interval $U.$ Every solution on subintervals of $U$ is  a restriction of $y.$

$Proof.$

Writing the equation in terms of the real and imaginary parts yields
$
u''(x)+iv''(x)+(a+bi)(u'(x)+iv'(x))+(c+mi)(u(x)+iv(x)) = 0 \\
\iff u''(x)+ au'(x)-bv'(x)+cu(x)-mv(x)+i\big[v''(x)+av'(x)+bu'(x)+cv(x)+mu(x)\big]=0 \\
\iff
\begin{cases} 
    u''(x)+au'(x)-bv'(x)+cu(x)-mv(x)=0 \\
    v''(x)+av'(x)+bu'(x)+cv(x)+mu(x)=0
   \end{cases}\\
\iff
\begin{cases} 
    u''(x)+au'(x)+cu(x)=\: bv'(x)+mv(x) \\
    v''(x)+av'(x)+cv(x)\:=-bu'(x)-mu(x)
   \end{cases} \\
$

This is a system of two linear second order differential equations with real coefficients. It is known that this reduces to a system of first order equations. Hence the theorem follows from uniqueness and existence of solutions for systems of first order linear equations. Q.E.D

Comment: Yes, that is correct.